# How to access single channel matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to ask if it is possible to access single channel matrix using `img.at<T>(y, x)` instead using `img.ptr<T>(y, x)[0]`

In the example below, I create a simple program to copy an image to another

```
cv::Mat inpImg = cv::imread("test.png");
cv::Mat img;  
inpImg.convertTo(img, CV_8UC1); // single channel image

cv::Mat outImg(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);

for(int a = 0; a < img.cols; a++)
    for(int b = 0; b < img.rows; b++)
        outImg.at<uchar>(b, a) = img.at<uchar>(b, a);   // This is wrong

cv::imshow("Test", outImg);
```

The shown result was wrong, but if I change it to

```
outImg.ptr<uchar>(b, a)[0] = img.ptr<uchar>(b, a)[0];
```

The result was correct.

I'm quite puzzled since using `img.at<T>(y, x)`  should also be okay. I also tried with 32FC1 and float, the result is similar.

Comment: It works OK on my PC. Not sure about the problem here...

Comment: Btw you can just do Mat outImg = img.clone();

Comment: no, my actual question is to access the pixels of a matrix, not to copy it, my code is only to test the problem

Answer (score 3):

Although I know you already found it, the real reason - buried nicely in the documentation - is that [`cv::convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#mat-convertto) ignores the number of channels implied by the output type, so when you do this:

```
inpImg.convertTo(img, CV_8UC1);
```

And, assuming your input image has three channels, you actually end up with a `CV_8UC3` format, which explains why your initial workaround was successful - effectively, you only took a single channel by doing this:

```
outImg.ptr<uchar>(b, a)[0]     // takes the first channel of a CV_8UC3
```

This only worked by accident as the pixel should have been accessed like this:

```
outImg.ptr<Vec3b>(b, a)[0]     // takes the blue channel of a CV_8UC3
```

As the data is still packed `uchar` in both cases, the effective reinterpretation happened to work.

As you noted, you can either convert to greyscale on loading:

```
cv::imread("test.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
```

Or, you can convert explicitly:

```
cv::cvtColor(inpImg, inpImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```